# JSONConvert DeserializeObject with nested array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, json, json.net

I have a model that contains and array of a different object type. The parent object deserializes fine but the nested array constantly fails.

Here are my objects:

```
public class VenueRoomViewModel
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public decimal HourCost { get; set; }
  public decimal DayCost { get; set; }
  public int MaxDelegate { get; set; }
  public string SpecialNotes { get; set; }
  public string Status { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("AssociatedFacilities")]
  public List<FacilityViewModel> AssociatedFacilities { get; set; }
}

public class FacilityViewModel
{
  public string FacilityName { get; set; }
  public int FacilityNo { get; set; }
  public string FacilityStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I try and parse the json like this:

```
VenueRoomViewModel myVM = sonConvert.DeserializeObject<VenueRoomViewModel>(jsonModel);
```

and here is a copy of the json that it is trying to parse:

```
"{\"State\":1,\"No\":\"0\",\"Name\":\"test\",\"HourCost\":\"12\",\"DayCost\":\"12\",\"MaxDelegate\":\"12\",\"SpecialNotes\":\"blah blah blah\",\"Status\":\"A\",\"AssociatedFacilities\":\"[{\\\"FacilityStatus\\\":1,\\\"FacilityNo\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"FacilityName\\\":\\\"Overhead Projector\\\"},{\\\"FacilityStatus\\\":1,\\\"FacilityNo\\\":\\\"5\\\",\\\"FacilityName\\\":\\\"New Facility\\\"}]\",\"VenueNo\":\"2\"}"
```

If I parse the objects individually then it works fine but I can't seem to get it to work just parsing the string

```
var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonModel, converter);
List<FacilityViewModel> facilities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FacilityViewModel>>(obj.AssociatedFacilities);
```

this parses the nested array fine so I think the json is ok.

Here's it working https://dotnetfiddle.net/znMYDZ

Comment: `FacilityStatus` is an `int` in the data but a `string` in the model? And `FacilityNo` is the inverse of that. Think those types need swapping.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your JSON encodes your `AssociatedFacilities` as a string. Try:

```
var json = @"{
  ""State"": 1,
  ""No"": ""0"",
  ""Name"": ""test"",
  ""HourCost"": ""12"",
  ""DayCost"": ""12"",
  ""MaxDelegate"": ""12"",
  ""SpecialNotes"": ""blah blah blah"",
  ""Status"": ""A"",
  ""AssociatedFacilities"": [{""FacilityStatus"":1,""FacilityNo"":""1"",""FacilityName"":""Overhead Projector""},{""FacilityStatus"":1,""FacilityNo"":""5"",""FacilityName"":""New Facility""}],
  ""VenueNo"": ""2""
}";

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VenueRoomViewModel>(json);
```

Comment: I think you're right. I am having to stuff it in a hidden field which is saved when the parent entity is saved. For whatever reason, i need to do it this way. How can I get around this?

Comment: @GrahamJRoy maybe you could deserialize your hidden field contents as `List<FacilityViewModel>` and resersialize that to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You json is different than the one from https://dotnetfiddle.net/znMYDZ
The model from your Json should be:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int State { get; set; }
    public string No { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HourCost { get; set; }
    public string DayCost { get; set; }
    public string MaxDelegate { get; set; }
    public string SpecialNotes { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string AssociatedFacilities { get; set; }
    public string VenueNo { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you want to use your model the Json should be like your exemple:

```
    string json = @"
        {""Name"":""Test Room"",
            ""HourCost"":1.72,
            ""DayCost"":12.55,
            ""MaxDelegate"":10,
            ""SpecialNotes"":""This room has been added in the unit tests"",
            ""Status"":""A"",
            ""AssociatedFacilities"":[{
                ""FacilityStatus"":1,
                ""FacilityNo"":""4"",
                ""FacilityName"":""Practical Area""},
                {""FacilityStatus"":1,
                ""FacilityNo"":""1"",
                ""FacilityName"":""Overhead Projector""}],
            ""No"":2352,
            ""EditCounter"":0,
            ""VenueNo"":2,
            ""State"":2}";
```